# Using Flot with multiple bars with orderbars.js and categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot

I am having trouble creating multiple bars with flot.  There is a plugin that can be downloaded here: http://www.benjaminbuffet.com/public/js/jquery.flot.orderBars.js that makes graphs with multiple bars per x category like this:  http://www.pikemere.co.uk/blog/tutorial-flot-how-to-create-bar-charts/ (see under the customized bar charts).  However, his example is a bit different in that it uses the time function rather than categories.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/flot/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/flot/jquery.flot.js"> </script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/flot/jquery.flot.categories.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/flot/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var data1 = [
        {
        label: "Male" ,
        data: [["True", 1],["False", 2]] ,
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: 0.13,
            order: 1
            }
        },
        {
        label: "Female" ,
        data: [["True", 3],["False", 4]],
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: 0.13,
            order: 2
            }
        }           
        ];

        $.plot($("#placeholder"), data1, {      
        xaxis: {
            mode: "categories"
        },

        });
    });
</script>


<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

With the above code, the graph displays, but without any bars.  If I remove the order:1 and order:2, it displays correctly, except with the bars overlapping each other rather than being offset by each other (I think it just ignores the orderbars plugin).

This is a very simplified example of what I really want to do, but if someone knows how I can get it to do what I want fairly simply, I would be very much appreciative.

To sum up, what I want is to have two sets of two bars.  The first set with "True" under them and the second second set with "False" under them.  I do not want to use numbers to represent the values, if possible as it will greatly complicate my more complex situation.  But if I must, I would still like to know how to do it that way.

Comment: First of all you dont need to go for orderbars.js for what you are depicting in your question.That can be done using flot alone.Are you looking for [jquery flot bar chart multiple series](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640040/jquery-flot-bar-chart-multiple-series)

Comment: Thank you Captain, but that solution appears to use the mode: 'time' for the x axis rather than the mode: "categories".  Unfortunately, using the "time" mode won't work for me in my situation.  Perhaps I am missing something though?

Comment: which flot version r u using? use latest stable version 0.8

Comment: I'm using .81 right now.  I think I made a confusing statement in my comment above.  Using the time mode will work for me, I just would rather use the categories mode because I am dynamically creating the graphs with php, and using the time mode makes it very difficult to do what I want to do.

Comment: this answers it 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21209473/plotting-multiple-barcharts-using-flot-api

Answer (score 3):

change the function getAxeMinMaxValues in orderBars.js

```
function getAxeMinMaxValues(series, AxeIdx) {
        var minMaxValues = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
          series[i].data[series[i].data.length - 1][AxeIdx];
            minMaxValues[0] = 0;
            minMaxValues[1] = series[i].data.length - 1;
        }
        return minMaxValues;
    }
```

hope this will help