# Plotting Multiple barcharts using Flot API

Tags: flot, bar-chart

hi i am using FLOT charts API to show data in the form of bar charts in my application. I have got requirement to show the data in bar chart and in categories with Pre Data and Post data some thing as shown in the picture like this

## Sample Diagram

[image: Sample Chart to plot]

Please tell me how to take the data to plot the bar chart

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a plugin for this.

Check [**OrderBars**](http://www.benjaminbuffet.com/public/js/jquery.flot.orderBars.js) and then use data like:

```
var series = [];

series.push({
    data: [], // your raw data
    bars: {
        order: 0
    }
});

series.push({
    data: [], // your raw data
    bars: {
        order: 1
    }
});
```

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRXP5/**
My example uses Mootools, but you find the jQuery version (.js file) in the link above.